# SQL Server - ADD '%' after my dynamic @VARIABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamicquery

I've been tasked with coming up with a means of translating the following data:
FROM

```
2017-04-01 12:16:58.5080000
2017-04-02 18:11:53.3090000
2017-04-02 18:34:18.3090000
2017-04-02 20:42:28.8570000
2017-04-02 21:10:36.7070000
2016-11-16 10:37:57.5970000
2016-11-16 10:38:07.7850000
2016-11-16 10:38:55.7010000
2016-11-16 10:48:19.0390000
2016-11-16 10:48:19.2990000
2016-11-16 10:48:29.3030000
2016-11-16 11:09:04.7960000
2016-11-16 11:15:08.1390000
2016-11-16 11:15:08.4190000
2016-11-16 11:14:27.4950000
.
.
.
```

TO

```
'2017-03%', '2017-02%', '2017-01%', '2016-12%', '2016-11%', '2016-10%'
```

---

> I have already written a code, where I get almost everything corect.
>   But i don't know **how to "inject" the percent %** after the '2016-12'
>   .

```
DECLARE @DatesFor NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT
    @DatesFor +=
    QUOTENAME(LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, [OccuredAtUtc])-1 , 0),120),7), '''') + ', '
FROM [DATABASE]
GROUP BY dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, [OccuredAtUtc])-1 , 0)
ORDER BY dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, [OccuredAtUtc])-1 , 0) DESC
SET @DatesFor = LEFT(@DatesFor, LEN(@DatesFor)- 1) -- delete the last comma
PRINT @DatesFor
```

> I get data without the % after month-->

```
'2017-03', '2017-02', '2017-01', '2016-12', '2016-11', '2016-10', '2015-01'
```

Is there any way, how to solve this ? #IBelieveThereIsAlwaysAWay

- or is there a way to add a symbol → ' ← to the declared string?

**I need an output to stay in the @DatesFor variable**, because after this I will be able to rework the result easily from '2017-03%' to "[OccuredAtUtc] LIKE '2017-03%' OR" and use it in my dynamic pivot query

Comment: This looks to be over complicated to me but I can't understand the output. I suspect that you could probably rework your dynamic pivot so this isn't so complicated. Perhaps we should focus on that instead of this strange date manipulation.

Comment: Change the `QuoteName` statement to... `QUOTENAME(LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, [OccuredAtUtc])-1 , 0),120),7)+'%', '''')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (OccuredAtUtc datetime2)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2017-04-01 12:16:58.5080000'),
('2017-04-02 18:11:53.3090000'),
('2017-04-02 18:34:18.3090000'),
('2017-04-02 20:42:28.8570000'),
('2017-04-02 21:10:36.7070000'),
('2016-11-16 10:37:57.5970000'),
('2016-11-16 10:38:07.7850000'),
('2016-11-16 10:38:55.7010000'),
('2016-11-16 10:48:19.0390000'),
('2016-11-16 10:48:19.2990000'),
('2016-11-16 10:48:29.3030000'),
('2016-11-16 11:09:04.7960000'),
('2016-11-16 11:15:08.1390000'),
('2016-11-16 11:15:08.4190000'),
('2016-11-16 11:14:27.4950000')

DECLARE @DatesFor NVARCHAR(MAX) = '>>>'

Select @DatesFor = replace(@DatesFor+concat('OR [OccuredAtUtc] LIKE ''',S,'%'' '),'>>>OR ','')
 From (
        Select Distinct Top 100 Percent S = Format(OccuredAtUtc,'yyyy-MM') From @YourTable Order By 1
      ) A
```

**Returns**

```
 [OccuredAtUtc] LIKE '2016-11%' OR [OccuredAtUtc] LIKE '2017-04%'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It is working exactly how i needed. Is there a way how to order the output by [OccuredAtUtc] ?

`DECLARE @DatesFor NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT TOP (4) @DatesFor = @DatesFor+concat('[OccuredAtUtc] LIKE ''',S,'%'' OR ')
 From (
        Select Distinct S = Format([OccuredAtUtc], 'yyyy-MM')
  FROM @Table 
      ) A
SET @DatesFor = LEFT(@DatesFor, LEN(@DatesFor)- 4)
PRINT @DatesFor`

Comment: @RadimŠafrán I have no idea what you are asking in the comment.  Edit your question so you can take advantage of formatting and such

Comment: @RadimŠafrán Perhaps you can add an ORDER BY 1 in the sub-query

Comment: The final output is not ordered. Is there any smart way, how to put there ORDER BY [OccuredAtUtc] so dates will be displayed sorted by month?
[2017-04], [2017-03], [2017-02] ... 
PS: Sorry for wasting your time John

Comment: @RadimŠafrán  Select Distinct Top 100 Percent S = Format(OccuredAtUtc,'yyyy-MM') From YourTable Order By 1

Comment: i tried it but it says
"Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified." Never mind, thank you John, u helped me so much

Comment: @RadimŠafrán see my comment above.  You can do Order By with a Top clause.  For example  Select Distinct Top 100 Percent ... Order By 1